# How do I implement the below view in iOS (Objective-C or Swift)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, swift3

Basically I'm trying to implement the feature which is attached as an image. I'm trying to create generic component. Where view can have list of items and minimum that could be shown will be two and there should be a button with 3 more options and click on should expand the view and auto adjust with the container using auto layout. Can any one help me giving brief idea how do I implement this? would be really help full.

Image and Component that I'm trying to implement is as below:

[image]

Comment: Why is it -1 for asking the question? Did i ask something wrong??? Just wondering!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will use `UITableView` with 2 `UICustomCell` one for default view like your image and another for expand view, use `NSMutableArray` to save flag value that decide to use the first cell or second cell, and in UIButton action reset this array and reload your UITableView.

I hope I help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) If I right understand, the flexible solution it's creating `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionView` as one of subviews (another - `UIImageView`). `UICollectionView` has two kinds of cells:

- Cell with label - **item**.
- **Show more** button.

Each time when you press **Show more** button just can reload **UICollectionView** without restrictions or insert new items.
But in this case you should manually calculate tableview's height. Implement `sizeThatFits` in `UITableViewCell`.

2) Also can add `UIStackView` and use it for your goal but `UIStackView` has bad performance.

Hope it helps you!